# How to include output of one XSLT file in another?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Is there any way of server side include XSLT file?
I mean that the output of one file is shown in the second file?

For example:

Main XSLT file:

```
<xsl:template match="pt">
  <xsl:comment>#include virtual="a.xsl"</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

Second XSLT file `a.xslt`:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:variable name="ab" select="'ss'"/>
   <p><xsl:value-of select="$ab"/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Now output will be

> ss in `p` tag

Why I am doing it like this is because I break my pages into multiple components after that I include their output in the main XSLT file. Each XSLT file has individual XML data.

Comment: You probably need to read up on `xsl:include` (and `xsl:import`). See http://www.xml.com/pub/2000/11/01/xslt/index.html, for example.

Comment: @TimC xsl:include (and xsl:import used include file and used there template using calltemplate ..I need different thing

Comment: @TimC xsl:include (and xsl:import used include file and used there template using calltemplate ..I need different thing .example if write <include-html>a.xslt</include-html>.it include call code a.xslt

Comment: @TimC may be that is called server side include .I will exaplain one more time ..Let take example you have two file .a.xsl and b.xsl .Now you import/include  b.xsl in a.xsl you can use all function and variable using `call-template` .I don't want to do this .I want whenever I include b.xml with tag example (<include-html>b.xsl</include-html>).it gives or returm be template b.xsl output

Comment: see my above example when I include`<xsl:comment>#include virtual="a.xsl"</xsl:comment>` it give me output $ab output with `p` tag

Comment: Will I  change my parser or is there any way in xslt we can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the output of an XSLT stylesheet as input to transform it again in vanilla XSLT 1.0 in a single stylesheet.

You either need to run the XSLT processor twice, using the result of the first pass as input for the second, or you need to use a processor that supports something like `node-set()`, which allows to convert a result tree fragment back to a node-set for further processing.

https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html

You can include arbitrary XML in the output however, as long as it is valid XML, using the `document()` function.

**stylesheet.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <externalData>
      <xsl:copy-of select ="document('some.xml')"/>
    </externalData>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**some.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
  <foo>bar</foo>
</content>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<externalData>
  <content>
    <foo>bar</foo>
  </content>
</externalData>
```